# Attempt to invoke virtual method com.android.volley.Request

Tags: java, android, context, android-volley

Я новичок в андроид программирование и столкнулся вот с такой проблемой который сам не смог решить.
Полный текст ошибки выглядит так:

```
10-28 10:41:38.752 7392-7392/com.jumagames.birdseggs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.jumagames.birdseggs, PID: 7392
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.Request com.android.volley.RequestQueue.add(com.android.volley.Request)' on a null object reference
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:255)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:193)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:184)
        at news.CardAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CardAdapter.java:91)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1858)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:407)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:628)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
10-28 10:43:01.427 7392-7392/com.jumagames.birdseggs I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7392 SIG: 9
```

Вот так вызывается метод(ошибка на 7-й строке):

```java
    public void onBindViewHolder(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        if (viewHolder instanceof ViewHolder) {
            News news2 = this.Newz.get(i);
            ViewHolder viewHolder2 = (ViewHolder) viewHolder;
            if (viewHolder2.news_image.getDrawable() == null && news2.getImage() != null) {
                this.imageLoader = ImageVolleyRequest.getInstance(this.context).getImageLoader();
                this.imageLoader.get(news2.getImage(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(viewHolder2.news_image, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_help));
            }
            viewHolder2.news_image.setImageUrl(news2.getImage(), this.imageLoader);
            viewHolder2.txtTitle.setText(news2.getTitle());
            viewHolder2.txtDate.setText(news2.getDate());
            viewHolder2.txtShortText.setText(Html.fromHtml(news2.getShort_text()));
            viewHolder2.txtId.setText(news2.getId());
            return;
        }
        ((ProgressViewHolder) viewHolder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
```

А вот мой ImageVolleyRequest класс:

```java
package news;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageCache;

import androidx.collection.LruCache;

public class ImageVolleyRequest {
    private static Context context;
    private static ImageVolleyRequest customVolleyRequest;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.requestQueue, new ImageCache() {
        private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<>(20);

        public Bitmap getBitmap(String str) {
            return this.cache.get(str);
        }

        public void putBitmap(String str, Bitmap bitmap) {
            this.cache.put(str, bitmap);
        }
    });
    private RequestQueue requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

    private ImageVolleyRequest(Context context2) {
        context = context2;
    }

    public static synchronized ImageVolleyRequest getInstance(Context context2) {
        ImageVolleyRequest imageVolleyRequest;
        context = context2;
        synchronized (ImageVolleyRequest.class) {
            if (customVolleyRequest == null) {
                customVolleyRequest = new ImageVolleyRequest(context2);
            }
            imageVolleyRequest = customVolleyRequest;
        }
        return imageVolleyRequest;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (this.requestQueue == null) {
            this.requestQueue = new RequestQueue(new DiskBasedCache(context.getCacheDir(), 10485760), new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack()));
            this.requestQueue.start();
        }
        return this.requestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return this.imageLoader;
    }
}
```

Comment: Нужен полный stack trace.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Добавил ошибку полностью

Comment: Поменяйте местами инициализацию `imageLoader` и `requestQueue` - вы передаёте в конструктор ссылку `this.requestQueue` до того как ей присвоено значение.

Comment: @woesss Спасибо Вам. Помогло.
Добавьте ваше решение как ответ чтобы я мог указать его как правильный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поля инициализируются в порядке объявления.
И получается что вы передаёте в конструктор `ImageLoader` ссылку `this.requestQueue` до того как ей присвоено значение.
Нужно поменять местами инициализацию `imageLoader` и `requestQueue`